# NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPolygon sending JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to recieve a json , using next class

```
 public class LayerData : DataObject
    {
        [PrimaryKeyField("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [PrimaryKeyField("identifier")]
        public Guid Identifier { get; set; }

        [DataField("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataField("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [DataField("coordinates")]
        public NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPolygon Coordinates { get; set; }

        [DataField("type")]
        public long Type { get; set; }

        [DataField("layer_id")]
        public long LayerId { get; set; }

    }
```

I get problem when sending NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPolygon with

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
"StackTrace": " at NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPolygon.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n
```

When i call get i recieve this JSON

```
{
    "Id": 739,
    "Identifier": "570a2848-88b0-467f-b4aa-da693f6b12b2",
    "Name": "test",
    "Value": "gsdfsdf",
    "Coordinates": [{
        "X": 2.0,
        "Y": 3.0
    },
    {
        "X": 4.0,
        "Y": 5.0
    }],
    "Type": 1,
    "LayerId": 4
}
```

but when i try to post i get those errors

```
{
    "Identifier":"571a2848-88b0-467f-b4aa-da693f6b12b2",
    "Name": "test",
    "Value": "gsdfsdf",
    "Coordinates": [{
        "X": 2.0,
        "Y": 3.0
    },
    {
        "X": 4.0,
        "Y": 5.0
    }],
    "Type": 1,
    "LayerId": 4
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't want ? In theory if i receive a type of Json i can resend it using same structure.

Comment: Are you able to serialize the JSON you get to that class? Also are you certain that same class used is on the server side for deserialization?

Comment: there is an example above what json i get and what json i send , the idea the json that i send doesnt work

Comment: ok, I have an idea just wanted to get some confirmation. posted my answer anyway based on an assumption. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which JSON deserializer you are using, but I think your problem is that nothing creates the instance for the `Coordinates` property in your target `LayerData` instance.

I'd either add a constructor to `LayerData` which initializes `Coordinates` like this:

```
public LayerData()
{
    Coordinates = new NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPolygon();
}
```

Or initialize the property of the instance before passing it to the deserializer, like this:

```
layerData.Coordinates = new NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPolygon();
```

**EDIT 1**

I had a couple minutes, so I created a simple test:

```
using System;
using NpgsqlTypes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace NpgsqlTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new TestDto
            {
                Coord = new NpgsqlPolygon(
                    new NpgsqlPoint(2.0, 3.0),
                    new NpgsqlPoint(4.0, 5.0)
                )
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestDto>(json);
            double x = result.Coord[0].X;
        }
    }

    public class TestDto
    {
        public NpgsqlPolygon Coord { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Running this, I got the same null-reference exception. Specifically the `Add` method of `NpgsqlPolygon` was throwing the exception. Huh?

So I went to [github and looked at the Npgsql source](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/develop/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlTypes/NpgsqlTypes.cs). The implementation of `NpgsqlPolygon` uses a private field called `_points` to hold the list of coordinates. The problem is that it is a `struct` and doesn't have a default constructor, but the `_points` field is only initialized in constructors. If you use default construction (which is what the Newtonsoft deserializer will do), that `_points` field never gets initialized.

Manually constructing an instance and adding a value to it has the same problem:

```
var coord = new NpgsqlPolygon();
coord.Add(new NpgsqlPoint(1.0, 2.0)); // throws exception
```

However, you can use one of the non-default constructors and it will work:

```
var coord = new NpgsqlPolygon(1);
coord.Add(new NpgsqlPoint(1.0, 2.0)); // no exception this time
```

This appears to be a bug in the current version of Npgsql (3.0.2 is what I got from NuGet).

I tried a couple things to get deserialization to work, like adding a constructor to my `TestDto` class or using `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` on an instance that I had properly constructed, but neither worked.

At this point, my suggestions would be:

- Try a different serializer (you'll need to add a constructor to properly initialize the property).
- Pull the Npgsql source from github and build your own version with the necessary fix.

**EDIT 2**

Another thing to keep in mind is that `NpgsqlTypes` are defined by an ADO.NET provider. As such, it is a questionable practice to use them outside of something like a data layer. They also appear to be intended to be treated as immutable (even though the `NpgsqlPolygon` struct implements `IList<>` which implies mutability).

You didn't give any context to where the JSON you are using to populate your `LayerData` class is being used, but to me, serialization implies that it is being used to propagate data across tiers.

So a better solution might be to create a set of custom classes to represent the polygon data in your data contract class, then implement some kind of data mapper in your data layer to write it into properly-constructed `NpgsqlPolygon` instances.

Comment: i am using newtonsoft.Json , if i use any other object i create it works fine , but when i use this headache i cant pass those coordinates

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON "coordinates" is an array but in the class it's a single class. That also kinda explains why it fails on IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() because it's treating it as a list.

To give an idea how to fix it you can try using json2chsarp.com to generate the classes you can use to deserialize that JSON. From the sample it generated the following:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<Coordinate> Coordinates { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int LayerId { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see Coordinates is generated as a List